# Método indefinido em Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, método

Estou tentando fazer um relacionamento entre duas tabelas em Ruby, onde utilizo o aluno e notas mas quando vou entrar em localhost:3000/students/1/notes ele me gera o erro [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

o meu notes_controller.rb:

```
class NotesController < ApplicationController
def index
    @student = Note.find(params[:student_id])
    @notes = @student.notes
end
```

end

notes.rb

```
class Note < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :student end
```

student.rb

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
has_many :notes , dependent: :destroy
```

end

Alguma ideia do porque ele diz que o metodo notes está indefinido?

Comment: Qual é o método Note ?  provavelmente você está acessando ele de uma maneira que ele não permite ser chamado, se ele estiver' def self.Note 'você consegue acessar com Note.find() mas se estiver 'def Note' você chama Note.new.find();

Comment: tentei utilizar o Note.new.find(), porém deu que o metodo find é indefinido.

Comment: Pelo pouco que entendo de ruby, o Note é uma classe, não um método, e vocẽ está acessando como se fosse um método, você só está dizendo em Notes que ele pertence a student (o que não está errado também ?, não deveria ser Student ?), e ter um método para setar Notes.Metodo.find(params[:student_id]), acho que assim irá funcionar, mas o que eu posso/sei palpitar acaba por aqui.

Comment: Realmente eu havia trocado as bolas. Substituir Note.find() por Student.find e funcinou. Obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 0):

Você está dizendo que **Note** pertence a **Student**, e tentando acessar de uma forma que ele não irá permitir, e terá a resposta de erro:

> noMethodError in NotesController#index
>   undefined method 'notes' for #

Pra resolver, assim como foi concluido nos comentários, acesse a classe **Student** e chame nela o método `.find()`

```
@student = Student.find(params[:student_id])
```